# Unabated can be adverb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

[image: from Oxfords dictionary]

I think that rage is verb so the following word should be adv. —> unabatedly.

Plus, rage isn’t linking v.

Thank you for your explanation in advance.

Comment: *Unabatedly*, which is rarely used, would certainly be grammatically correct, but *The storm was raging unabated* is more idiomatic. *The storm **continued** unabated* is grammatically correct as *continue* is a link verb. Although you are right in saying 'rage' doesn't appear on any list of such verbs, it must be functioning as a link verb here. Ngram has scores of examples of "burned unabated", the earliest being from 1827, so it isn't new. But these days we drive *fast* more than we drive *quickly*. We tell children to *hold on tight*. We ask them, *How are you?* and they say, *Good*.